# Measure screen dimensions in cm/inches in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

How can i measure the screen dimensions of the screen in cm/inches, no matter what resolution is used in the monitor. I am new to image processing/graphics. Can anyone suggest a good starting point in .net

Comment: You can't do this reliably.

Comment: You really can't, but why would this information be useful, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ben Robinson , We are working on a project that will require real world measurements so that we can print/design the image on specified dimensions in cm or inch

Comment: Real world measurements of what?

Comment: @Ben Robinson an image, like this so and so image should be 10 cm by 10 cm